# hibernate many to many insert only student and mapping tables

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I have student, test and student_test tables with many-to-many relationship.

Test:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class Test 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TEST_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long testId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT")
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "MAX_MARKS")
    private String maxMarks;

    @Column(name = "MARKS_OBTAINED")
    private String marksObtained;

    @Column(name = "RESULT")
    private String result;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
                mappedBy = "test", 
                cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST})

    private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<Student>();
}
```

Student:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long studentId;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_TEST", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID", updatable = false) }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TEST_ID", updatable = false) })
    private Set<Test> test = new HashSet<Test>();
 }
```

I have created test record separately.
Now I wanted to insert a Student with relationship record.

The following code is trying to 
update student record
update test record
insert a record in relationship table (student_test).

```
Test test1 = new Test();
test1.setTestId(Long.valueOf("3"));

student1.getTest().add(test1);
student1.setStudentId(Long.valueOf("1"));

try  
{
    session.saveOrUpdate(student1);
} 

catch (HibernateException e)  
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();`
```

My question is, I need to insert a record into Student and relationship table(student_test) only and it should not update record in test table.

Comment: Why do you set ids manually when you use @GeneratedValue annotation?

Comment: `My question is, I need to insert a record into Student and relationship table(student_test) only and it should not update record in test table.` Sorry, but that's not a question, that's a request.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you forgot to begin transaction. Add following line before `saveUpdate`

```
   session.getTransaction().begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing seems ok except your transaction management.. But I did not see the transaction open in your posted code but  you have only transaction commit..  can you make the change and do test again ?

Cheers!